# primefaces отключение авто обновления от remoteCommand

Tags: jsf, primefaces

Есть проект где используется jsf+primefaces Используется таблица `<p:dataTable ...>` с фильтром.
так же в проекте используется  `<p:remoteCommand ...>` т.к. у сервера есть ограничения на использование wss, я вызываю каждую секунду remoteCommand. Причем моя таблица каждый раз пересчитывает значение фильтра. Как убрать автоматическое "обновление" таблицы? пробовал `ignoreAutoUpdate="true"` и `update="@none"` и т.д., не помагает. При нажатии на кнопки та же ситуация - перечет фильтра.

```
<p:remoteCommand name="comand" />
<h:form id="f"> 
<p:dataTable id="tbl"
  widgetVar="tbl"
  value="#{bean.list}"
  filteredValue="#{bean.flist}"
 >
 <f:facet name="header">
  <p:outputPanel>
    <p:inputText id="globalFilter" value="#{bean.fieldSearch}" onchange="PF('tbl').filter();"/>
  </p:outputPanel>
 </f:facet>
<p:column>***</p:column>
<p:column>***</p:column>
</p:dataTable>
</form>
```

Comment: А почему p:remoteCommand объявлена вне формы? Она вроде вообще неработоспособна от этого должна стать.

Comment: как ни станно и вне формы работает и с формой... Пробовал в разные формы пихать. Все то же.

Comment: Попробуйте выложить в вопросе код, который позволит воспроизвести проблему в произвольном окружении, в отрыве от вашего проекта - целиком страницу, и серверный компонент. Для этого, вероятно, придётся создать новые, тестовые исходные коды. Возможно, такой процесс сам по себе поможет разобраться в проблеме самостоятельно.

Answer (score 0):

Можно попробовать:
`partialSubmit="true"` - чтобы осуществлять сабмит не всей формы, а только явно указанных компонентов.

`process="@this"` - передавать на сервер только непосредственно команду (`action`), не затрагивая никакие другие элементы.

Comment: пожалуйста, оставляйте чуть более развёрнутые ответы. [постарайтесь рассказать обо всех нюансах, которые могут возникнуть при решении проблемы по вашему сценарию. изложите свои предложения. возможен и краткий ответ, но чем подробнее и понятнее он будет изложен, тем лучше](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]

Comment: к сожалению не помогло.

Comment: если вызов `p:remoteCommand` осуществляется из JSF-элемента, то стоит проверить и его поведение и атрибуты

Comment: Возможно дело даже не в p:remoteCommand, а в настройках таблицы или неких "общих" настройках т.к. подобное обновление фильтра происходит при нажатии любой кнопки и обработки люббого ajax запроса.